# How to scale a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

In swift I've successfully made an animated `bezier path` which is contained inside a `CAShapeLayer`. My only problem is implementing it onto other screen sizes. Does anybody know how I can scale the `CAShapeLayer` with the path inside of it?
i.e. make it half the original size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this function:

```
 var shapelayer:CAShapeLayer
 shapelayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(, ,)
```

Comment: A simple solution is always best. Love it!